# Phonetical language spelling

Tags: meaning

Am I wrong in thinking that a phonetical language, for example Spanish, is a language where the words are spelt as they sound

Comment: Kind of. All spoken languages have a phonetic element; that is what they sound like. Some languages have more phonemic *writing systems* than others (phonemic = about contrastive, distinct sounds of a language). A writing system is not a language; there are languages with multiple writing systems, and languages with no writing systems. A relevant question: [What do you call languages with words that are pronounced the same way they are written?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234759/what-do-you-call-languages-with-words-that-are-pronounced-the-same-way-they-are)

Comment: It is a myth that Spanish is spelled phonetically. It’s not even spelled phonemically.

Comment: Spanish is far closer to "phonetic" than English is.  (But then English is such a hodge-podge it's likely one of the worst.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that a language itself is phonetic in that sense. It is the written form that can be described as phonetic or not.

Apart from that I would say you are correct. Note that written Spanish is not 100% phonetic. For example  'g' is pronounced differently according to which vowel it precedes and some varieties make no distinction in sound between 's' and 'z''.

Comment: <Thank you. Then my next question is what does it mean that Romanian spelling is phonemic

Comment: @Richard - It means that Romanian monolinguists believe this to be true, and teach foreigners who wish to learn the language to mispronounce everything based on that misguided belief.

Comment: Minor pedantic point: although language teachers often use "phonetic" to mean this, "phonemic" is a more precise word, since *phonetics* technically encompasses all the variations in sound, like the pitch of the speaker's voice, the speed, and the particular accent used.

Comment: Sorry, but not understanding what phonemic means

Comment: @sumelic: You're absolutely right. I always get annoyed when people say "melodic" when they really mean "melodious." What are you going to do, flog them in the square in front of the city hall? Yeah, I'm pretty frustrated here too.

Comment: More places where Spanish is not spelled as it sounds: h is silent outside of the digraph *ch*; b/v are not distinct, j/soft g are not distinct, z/soft c are not distinct, for most varieties y/ll are not distinct. And x is sometimes the same as j (like in *México*).

Answer (score -2):

There is no such thing as a phonetic alphabet. It's a myth popularized by people who either can't see the forest for the trees or have little knowledge of the language they have in mind, at least where European languages are concerned. European alphabets are ancient-Greek-based. No language today even remotely resembles ancient Greek pronunciation. Apart from that, the number of sounds a language has exceeds the number of letters in any Greek-based alphabet by orders of magnitude.

Attempts have been made to create phonetic alphabets, most of them in the beginning of the 20th Century. None of them were successful. What G.B. Shaw pointed out (in the preface to his play "Pygmalion") is still true today: the most frequently used vowel in the English language does not have its own letter.

Comment: I would say that  IPA is a successful phonetic alphabet.  It is not perfect but it is PDG. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - It would work if all of us were Irish. Tragically, some of us aren't. Whaddya gonna do.

Comment: English has around 50 phonemes. This is not "more than the number of letters by an order of magnitude."

Comment: @PeterShor: I hasten to submit, before everyone starts hating me for bringing him up all the time, that G.B. Shaw claimed there were 120 vowels alone in English. And that's just in London.

Comment: @Ricky:-  Irish? What's that got to do with anything? (or was that humour?)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - Welsh, Italian, Brooklynite Jews, Australian Greeks, Brazilian Ethiopians, it's all the same. So long as there's total agreement on how to pronounce sounds, IPA does work. Sort of. I chose Irish because I always do. My favorite people. You know: God created whiskey to keep them from taking over the world. It's funny because it's almost true.

Comment: G.B. Shaw was neither a phonetician nor a linguist. The phonetician he based Henry Higgins on would have distinguished that many phonetic variants because they're there -- every native speaker speaks their own version of English. But we don't notice the phonetic differences because we're hearing them phonemically. We're all aiming for pretty much [the same set of sounds](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf) and we grant one another a lot of latitude; indeed, we use vowel differences to mark our group affiliation and status, like ants leaving chemicals in their trail.

Comment: @Ricky I suspect that you have partaken of too much poteen tonight if your comments are anything to go by!

Comment: @JohnLawler - No, he wasn't, but he did invent his own (phonetic) shorthand, spelled Shakespeare as Shakespear, and for many years was an advocate of Sweet's Universal Alphabet, or whatever it's called. Of course we give one another plenty of leeway, and that is PRECISELY why no alphabet exists today that is truly phonetic. Or phonemic, for that matter. Look at the Chinese. People from different regions of China may not understand each other, but they can read and understand the same texts perfectly.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - So what. Maybe I have. Maybe I'm proud of it, too.

Comment: @Ricky: No, he didn't invent that, either. He left money for a prize to be awarded for the best English spelling system invented after his death. The result is the "[Shavian alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shavian_alphabet)", which has been used for two books in the last 50 years.

Comment: @JohnLawler - Well, that's not exactly Shaw's fault, right? People are who are lazy call themselves conservative or traditionalist to hide their sloth, even from themselves. I'm perfectly happy with the existing alphabet, by the way, I'm just being objective.